# How to get/select a bone by it's name in python?

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones

I am having a master armature which has multiple bones. Now I want to apply rotation to a particular bone. Now, I can loop through all the bones in the armature and check for the bone with the expected name and then process it. But is there a way to select/get the bone object directly using it's name without looping through all the bones?

Comment: Are you only interested in answers that involve Python? Because this can be done more easily in the Outliner if you don't need the process to be automated in a script. I can post an answer with screen shots if you like.

Comment: Thanks Mentalist for the reply. I am looking for python scripts for automation as you mentioned. Anyway thanks for the support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This also works
`bpy.data.objects["Armature"].data.bones["Jaw"].select = True`

Comment: Notably, this only works if you are not already in edit mode on the armature. Is that on purpose I wonder?

Answer (score 3):

Most collections in blender that you can iterate, where the items have a name property, can be accessed

```
item = collection["name"]
jaw_bone = obj.pose.bones["jaw"]
```

You can also use get, to avoid an error if an item of name doesn't exist

```
jaw_bone = obj.pose.bones.get("jaw")
if jaw_bone is not None:
    print("Jaw bone exists")
```

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER for the reply. I suspect this way of selection is based on pose mode? I found one more way of doing it. `bpy.data.objects['Armature'].data.bones.get('Bone')`. Can you tell me the difference of these ways of selection?

Comment: bpy.objects["Armature"].data = bpy.armatures["..."]  which are the defined bones of the rig (rest position).  The pose.bones collection on the armature object is for posing.  Explained better here http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?47073-Bone-Position-in-Edit-vs-Object-Mode&p=453448&viewfull=1#post453448

Comment: I think the `if jaw_bone is not None:`  can be shortened to `if jaw_bone:`  because the _.get_ either returns the object (and that evaluates always to a truthy value) or it returns None.

Comment: @zeffi agreed.  As an example it shows that it returns None if not defined, Could use collection.get("blah", False) as well, but that mixes objects and bools.  Matter of preference I suppose.